# Chromium kiosk mode across dual monitors

Tags: raspberry-pi, chrome

I am running the latest Raspbian on raspberrypi 4 with 2 HDMI touchscreen monitors. My goal is to have a chromium page open full screen across both screens.

I tried the solution posted here:
[Treat 2 displays as 1 in Raspbian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534467/treat-2-displays-as-1-in-raspbian)

Aka: 
https://gist.github.com/eslindsey/70bbc0080e335b38836fab09d19686d0

This Gist allows you to supply an arbitrary command (and optional arguments), and detects the created window and screen size automatically.

Concept

```
    chromium-browser --kiosk <url> &
    sleep 5
    wmctrl -r Chromium -b remove,fullscreen
    wmctrl -r Chromium -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
    wmctrl -r Chromium -e 0,0,0,3840,1080
```

The Chromium window does resize to fill the width of both screens, but the top minimize/maximize/close toolbar has re-opened, defeating the point of kiosk mode. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

*It took me hours of researching and try and error to find a solution. Resizing the window with wmctrl did only work, after I resized it once with my mouse and was therefore not suited for a mouse and keyboard-less setup. Furthermore did I want to achieve a true Fullscreen-mode for the best kiosk-like experience. This is how it finally worked for me:*

First set your second display in clone-mode, so that it clones display one (in my case at a Raspberry Pi 4 HDMI-1 and HDMI-2):

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --same-as HDMI-1
```

Next determine your screen dimensions:

```
xrandr
```

This gives you a list of connected screens and their resolutions. You then have to compute the total screen size of all monitors together by adding them up.
I attached two 1280x1024 monitors, so my total screen size combined is 2560x1024.
As xrandr does not allow us to set a screen size larger than the monitor itself via the `--fb` flag, we use the `--panning` option:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --panning 2560x1024+0+0/0x0+0+0/0/0/0/0
```

This sets a larger screen but only displays a portion of it on monitor 1. It also disables mouse panning, as we want monitor 2 to display the rest of the image.
Last we have to pan monitor 2 to the right half of the large screen with:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --pos 1280x0
```

and 1280 being the end of monitor 1.

You can now put the three commands in autostart to have them enabled on startup.

**Some final remarks:**

If you are on a SSH-Session, you have to add `DISPLAY=:0` at the beginning of your xrandr-commands (e.g. `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output HDMI-2 --same-as HDMI-1`).

When you want to achieve a videowall like look, you can easily implement bezel-compensation by enlarging your virtual screen. In my case the bezels of my monitor are roughly 64 pixels thick, so you would set your output on monitor 1 to 2624 instead of 2560. Then you set your second monitor to start at pos 1344x0 leaving 64 pixels not displayed.

*Links that helped:*

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214841
http://www.straightrunning.com/tools/xrandr.html#sect3
http://www.mshopf.de/pub/Fosdem_2009_randr13_Slides.pdf
[Treat 2 displays as 1 in Raspbian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534467/treat-2-displays-as-1-in-raspbian?noredirect=1&lq=1)

*Good luck!*

Comment: I managed to achieve similar results with this command: `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --panning 7680x2160+0+0 --output DP-4 --panning 3840x2160+3840+0`

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this post trying to do the same thing. After some wrangling, this process gets me to a two-monitor spanning Chromium window in kiosk mode:

```
chromium --kiosk http://localhost:1337
wmctrl -r Chromium -b remove,fullscreen
wmctrl -r Chromium -e 0,0,0,1600,1280
```

The tab bar is still there, and I discovered (by accident) that right-clicking on it brought up the "Undecorate" option, which mimics kiosk mode again.

I found this "toggle-decorations" command-line tool:
https://gist.github.com/cat-in-136/96ee8e96e81e0cc763d085ed697fe193

```
./toggle-decorations $(wmctrl -lx | grep -E "Chromium" | grep -oE "0x[0-9a-z]{8}")
```

Chromium is now kiosk-like again.

Hope this helps someone.